# MySQL count select query with condition

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, conditional-statements

I have a mysql table  called Game which has two columns, Name and Score. I want to select only the Names whose scores have been atleast 100 and atleast twice. In the below example Ron and Mary will get selected. I am not sure how to write the select statement for this.

Game table

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` with a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT Name
FROM mytable
GROUP BY Name
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Score >= 100 THEN 1 END) >= 2
```

`HAVING` clause checks for `Name` groups, having *at least two* records with `Score >= 100`.